# Why is g++ saying about ill-formed narrowing when it's clearly well-defined in given case?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Consider the code:

```
volatile unsigned int test;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
unsigned char arr[]={test&0xff};
```

Here whatever value `test` has, `test&0xff` will always fit into `unsigned char`. Still I get the compiler warning:

> warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(((unsigned int)test) & 255u)’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘unsigned char’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]

Is narrowing always ill-formed for *any* values in C++11?

Is there a way to retain clear code without explicit conversions, but not get warning (and errors with C++11 mode) in such cases as this?

Comment: inside the braced initialization you cant have conversion. i.e a braced initialization list must have elements that match exactly to the type its initializing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would put them together and still get a 32 bit int.  Yes, the values would technically fit into a char, but it's the type of the output from the operation, and not the data within.  Note that both test and 0xff would be 32 bits.  Try casting the output:

```
(unsigned char)(test & 0xff)
```

Comment: Yes, casting is an obvious solution. But it affects readability of code. That's why I ask if there's a nice trick to avoid it.

Comment: Using "tricks" to get things done usually breaks readability.

Comment: Casting doesn't reduce readability.  It's code.  It's what you need when you have a lossy data conversion - show that you intended the results.

Comment: Looking back, I now know that the most obvious solution to readability would be to just `typedef unsigned char truncate;` _locally_ (to avoid polluting namespace), and then do all the needed conversions like `truncate(test)`.